# List won't move with transform

Tags: css

I have a list that I'm trying to scroll from top to bottom (marquee fashion).  I'm using this CSS:

```
// Marquee CSS
.scrolling 
{ 
height: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

.scrolling a 
{ 
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
text-align: center;
color: white;

/* Starting position */

-moz-transform:translateY(-100%);
-webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);
transform:translateY(-100%);

/* Apply animation to this element */

-moz-animation: scrolling 15s linear infinite;
-webkit-animation: scrolling 15s linear infinite;
animation: scrolling 15s linear infinite;
}

.scrolling ul {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
text-align: center;

/* Starting position */

-moz-transform:translateY(-100%);
-webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);
transform:translateY(-100%);

/* Apply animation to this element */  
-moz-animation: scrolling 15s linear infinite;
-webkit-animation: scrolling 15s linear infinite;
animation: scrolling 15s linear infinite;
}

/* Move it (define the animation) */

@-moz-keyframes scrolling {
0%   { -moz-transform: translateY(0%); }
100% { -moz-transform: translateY(100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scrolling {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); }
}
@keyframes scrolling {
  0%   {
  transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  100% {
  transform: translateY(100%);
  } 
}
```

which works, sort of.  It does scroll my list, however it hides a large portion of the list.  The box size is just what I'm looking for, my list is entirely intact however it simply doesn't show the entire list when I try to scroll it.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The solution, it seems, is to increase the size of the transform ie from -100% (or 0%) to -600% to 600% - it allows for the list to be 12X the size of my box, I think.  If someone could confirm this is what I've done by changing those numbers I would certainly be grateful!